# Pass uploaded file between PHP scripts

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I've got a page where users can upload a HTML file for use as a theme. The HTML file has some checks performed on it before some options are displayed to the user. The user fills out the form in relation to the HTML file, and submits the form. However, due to the file in the temp folder being destroyed after the script has ended, I do not know how to get the HTML file once the form has been filled out and re-submitted short of making the user re-upload the file, which relies on them uploading the same file, and also makes them upload something twice, which is counter-intuitive and could be an issue with large files.
Here is the code (cut down to make it easier to read/understand). The form submits to itself, so the same PHP file is used for both "steps".

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Form has been submitted
    $files = $_FILES['file'];
    <form method="POST">
        /* Options about the uploaded HTML file are generated using PHP and displayed here */
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
} else {
    ?>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Theme File(s)</label>
        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

I tried using `<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" value="<?php echo $files; ?> >`, but this did not work, and would also require the user to re-upload the files, which could be any issue if the files get too big.
I was thinking there might be a way to pass the file internally, and have a check whether a file has been uploaded or passed to the script instead of `<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple">`, but I could not find a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own temporary file, and pass the name between your two scripts.

So for example, in your "first script" (i.e. when the file has first been uploaded) you would:

```
$uniqName = uniqid('upload_', TRUE);
$tmpFile = "/tmp/$uniqName.html";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][0], $tmpFile);
```

And then when you generate the form from the result of this upload, you would add

```
<input type="hidden" name="uniqName" value="<?php echo $uniqName; ?>" />
```

...so that when you get to your "second script" (after the questionnaire form is submitted) you can access the file through:

```
$tmpFile = "/tmp/".basename($_REQUEST['uniqName']).".html";
```

Of course, this is subject to the possibility of people failing to submit to second form so you end up with "orphaned files" littering your temporary directory, so you will need to implement some form of check that deletes files after thet have been inactive for a certain amount of time - you can base this on the last modified time of the files.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of how you can randomly run a job to keep the `/tmp` dir tidy without a cron job:

```
$probabilityDivisor = 10; // 1/10 chance of running
$uploadTTLSecs = 1800; // 30 minutes

if (mt_rand(1, $probabilityDivisor) / $probabilityDivisor == 1) {
  foreach (glob('/tmp/upload_*') as $file) {
    // Iterate files matching the uniqids you generate
    if (time() - filemtime($file) >= $uploadTTLSecs) {
      // If file is older than $uploadTTLSecs, delete it
      unlink($file);
    }
  }
}
```

This operates in a similar way to the PHP [session garbage collectors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor). Because of the simplicity of the operations, this should not adversely affect the user experience in any meaningful way.

Comment: I thought about something like this, but you have made it very clear for me, thanks you. Is there a way to delete these temp files without a cron job (the only way I know of doing it)?

Comment: You could randomly run a job when a file is uploaded (similar to the [Drupal poormanscron](http://drupal.org/project/poormanscron) module) I will edit with example code.

Comment: I will have to play with this some more, but overall it looks good. However, when I use `$tempFolderName = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . uniqid('upload_', TRUE) . '/';`, `$tempFolderName` has the value `C:\Windows\TEMP/upload_4ffc4373242041.76382376/`, which has 2 things wrong with it. 1) That is the windows temp folder, not the php one, which might cause issues(?) 2) How can I know to use "/" or "\"? I'm assuming that's OS based, but I'd like this to run on work across OSs. (Note: I wanted to put all the files in one folder in the PHP temp directory (out of public view) with a random name)

Comment: Also note: I could be completely wrong about number 1, and that could be the intended result; I simply thought it would be stored in the PHP `tmp` folder.

Comment: @JosephDuffy When running PHP on Windows, the PHP tempdir == The Windows tempdir - this will not cause a problem as long as the web server user has permissions to write to it (which it most likely will). You can use `/` on Windows and it will work, so I always just use `/` in every script for cross compatibility. However if you are worried about it you can use the [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant to get the system's default character.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. Use **move_uploaded_file()** and move the file from the temp location to a permanent location on the server. Be sure to give the file your moving a unique name like 'file-' . time() . '.jpg' or something.
2. Soon after uploading, register a Session variable and put the file name in it.
3. After everything is over you could delete the file using unset()

Now the file is located safely on your server and you also have access to it via the session.

Hope this helps :)